# PHP MVC Form Submission

Tags: php, forms, model-view-controller

I have a question related to form submission done in PHP application that's built in MVC architecture (self-written framework).

All examples that I've seen so far (including existing back-end frameworks) work this way that once form for adding record to database is submitted then certain method of controller is executed [say i.e. addRecord()], which triggers method of appropriate model. If everything goes OK then record is added and controller's method [addRecord() in this example] renders view of "index" page that displays table with records from database.

What I would like to achieve is to render view with form used to add records (the same that I used to add first record) instead of "index". Obviously I can do it easily by just rendering appropriate view from addRecord() (view with the form).

But the tricky point is when you check url you'll see the following:
The first time you enter it will be i.e.

```
http://project_name/my_controller/create
```

Once first form was submietted and you return to the view from addRecord() method then url will be:

```
http://project_name/my_controller/addRecord
```

What I would like to see is return to the original url, that is `http://project_name/my_controller/create`

Not sure if this is clear?

PS. Of course I could use AJAX call for form submission (that way I will stay at the same page) but perhaps it's possible to achieve the same without AJAX.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Since this is a self-written framework it will be hard to say how to accomplish this but you would just need to redirect on success for addRecord to create. I use slim as a controller and this is the normal MVC flow I create.

Comment: Hi Nerdyist, this is what I've been missing. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: I made it an answer if you want to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

On the controller you will want to submit to the addRecord route and do the processing. Have a check to make sure it was successful and on successful submission you can redirect back to the create route.

It is hard to give an example since you are using a custom made framework. I use slim which has a redirect method for a route. If what you have made does not have something like that then using should do the trick.

```
header('Location: '.$createUrl);
die(); //or exit
```